# Unable to locate package csh or tcsh

Tags: linux, ubuntu, package, csh, tcsh

[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CsJNi.png)

I tried it on both ubuntu 20.04 and 18.04 versions. I got the error in the photo I uploaded. I tried to install both "csh" and "tcsh" but got an error. Is there any way to download with "wget"? I would be glad if you could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enable `universe` repository:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt update
sudo apt install csh tcsh
```